# C - only scalar operations?

Tags: c, scalar

Reading on Wikipedia:

> "The terms high-level and low-level are inherently relative. Some decades ago, the C language, and similar languages, was most often considered "high-level", as it supported concepts such as expression evaluation, parameterised recursive functions, and data types and structures, while assembly language was considered "low-level". Many programmers today might refer to C as low-level, as it lacks a large runtime-system (no garbage collection etc), ***basically supports only scalar operations***, and provides direct memory addressing. It therefore readily blends with assembly language and the machine level of CPUs and microcontrollers."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_level_language

What does this mean exactly? What operations do other programming languages provide which C does not?

Comment: Contrast "scalar" with "aggregate" or "compound".

Comment: Any phrase that starts *"basically"* is dubious IMO and in the terms of Wikipedia not very 'encyclopaedic'.  Given AndreyT's answer, I suggest you edit the article to change *"basically"* to *"primarily"*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Given the context and topic of the article, what the article is referring to is the term "scalar" as it is defined in C language itself. In C language *arithmetic* types and *pointer* types together are called *scalar* types (see 6.2.5/21). In everyday language we often see these types referred to as *basic* types or *built-in* types (while the proper formal term is, again, *scalar*). The point is that *scalar* types are intended to be the types that are immediately (or almost immediately) supported by hardware. Most non-conceptual operations in C operate on scalar types and scalar types only.

If you take a look at the history of C language, you'll see that early versions of C were so restrictively *scalar*, that you couldn't even assign one struct object to another struct object (or pass it to a function/return from a function by value). The ability do the struct copying in the core language was added to C later. And to this day it remains essentially the only non-scalar operation in the entire core language.

C++, on the other hand, as well as other higher-level languages, supports operations on *user-defined* types, which are by definition not *scalar*, or on other types that have no immediate support from hardware.

P.S. No, the point the article is trying to make has nothing to do with *vector* operations, as opposed to *scalar* operations. Support for vector operations is, of course, completely orthogonal to the level of the language. You can have vector operations in low-level languages as well as in high-level languages. The term *scalar* is used in a sense that I described above.